# Is there a way of reshaping a multidimensional array into a 1-D Vector in Python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, reshape

so I'm trying to turn this array

```
   array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,1.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,0.]])
          [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0.]])
```

into this array

```
   array([ 0, 4, 9, 6, 0])
```

So each row of the original array, is replaced with a single value that is equal to where the "1" is located in the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
a = np.array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,1.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,0.],
          [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0.]])

print( np.argmax(a, axis=1) )
```

Prints:

```
[0 3 9 6 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array = np.array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,1.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,0.],
          [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0.]])
          
print(np.where(array == 1)[1]
```

Output:

```
array([0, 3, 9, 6, 0])
```